# Spring controller returns pdf inline with bad header

Tags: spring, http, pdf

I would like to open a pdf in a new tab so my Spring controller is so (I don't know why but I have to add .pdf even my url param has .pdf extension):

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_FLEET_ENG', 'ROLE_VIEW_ENG')")
@Override
@RequestMapping(value = { "applications/cars/acquisitions/pdf/{idAcquisition}/{pdfName}"},produces = "application/pdf", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<byte[]> showPdf(@PathVariable("idAcquisition") int idAcquisition, @PathVariable("pdfName") String pdfName){ 
    try {
        byte[] pdfContents = fleetAndCarService.showPdf(idAcquisition, pdfName + ".pdf");
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
         headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
         headers.add("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + pdfName +".pdf");
        ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(
                pdfContents, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        return response;    
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse= ErrorResponseBuilder.buildErrorResponse(e);
        LOG.error("Threw exception in FleetAndCarControllerImpl::showPdf :" + errorResponse.getStacktrace());
        //TODO what do I have to return?
        return null;
    }
}
```

but I receive 406 error : `The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.`
How do I have to configure my header?Thanks

Comment: Have you actually checked what a 406 is and what the error is telling you? It is telling you that you are requesting something but not a pdf. In your mapping you explicitly state that it returns `application/pdf` but your browser is probably having `text/html` and some other headers in there. those don't match hence an error. Added `.pdf` to the URL fixes this as that triggers the correct conversion as well as a header.

Comment: yes, it doesn't set pdf as accepted format. My Url is correct: http://localhost:8086/DART/fleetAndCar/applications/cars/acquisitions/pdf/179/13_Test2.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved with this code:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_FLEET_ENG', 'ROLE_VIEW_ENG')")
@Override
@RequestMapping(value = { "applications/cars/acquisitions/pdf/{idAcquisition}/{pdfName}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void showPdf(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable("idAcquisition") int idAcquisition, @PathVariable("pdfName") String pdfName){
    File pdfFile= null;;
    try {
        pdfFile = fleetAndCarService.showPdf(idAcquisition, pdfName + ".pdf");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse= ErrorResponseBuilder.buildErrorResponse(e);
        LOG.error("Threw exception in FleetAndCarControllerImpl::showPdf :" + errorResponse.getStacktrace());
    }
    try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream(pdfFile.getAbsolutePath()); ) {
        setResponse(response, is, pdfFile, "inline; filename=" );   
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse= ErrorResponseBuilder.buildErrorResponse(e);
        LOG.error("Threw exception in FleetAndCarControllerImpl::showPdf :" + errorResponse.getStacktrace());
    }   
}
```

and private method

```
private void setResponse(HttpServletResponse response, InputStream is, File file, String useOfFile) throws Exception{
        response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control","must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        response.setContentType(Files.probeContentType(file.toPath()));
        response.setHeader("Content-Description"," File Transfer");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", useOfFile + file.getName());
        response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding"," binary");
        long size = Utils.stream(is, response.getOutputStream());
        response.addHeader("Content-Length", Long.toString(size));
        response.flushBuffer();
    }
```